# What happens under the hood when using array initialization syntax to initialize a Dictionary instance on C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Does anyone know what C# compiler does under the hood with the following code?

```
dict = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 1, "value1" },
    { 2, "value2" }
}
```

It is not clear to if it creates the KeyValuePair instances and call the Add method, or do something more optimized. Does anyone of you know it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It'll call the `Add` method on the object with the values as arguments:

```
var __temp = new Dictionary<int, string>();
__temp.Add(1, "value1");
__temp.Add(2, "value2");
dict = __temp;
```

The name `Add` is hardcoded (specified in the C# spec: ***7.5.10.3***: Collection initializers). The number of arguments to the method is not limited. It just has to match the number of parameters of the method. Any collection (implementing `IEnumerable` interface) that provides an `Add` method can be used like that.

To further clarify, no, the compiler doesn't really care that the class is a `Dictionary` to create a `KeyValuePair` and pass that to `Add`. It simply generates a sequence of calls to the `Add` method passing all the arguments in each collection item in each call. The `Add` method is responsible for the rest.

Comment: One very slight correction here - the variable isn't assigned until *after* all the Add calls. Basically it's as if there's a temporary variable. It's a nitpick, but hey - we're going for "under the covers" here :) (It wasn't worth a separate answer though.) You may also want to mention that the collection has to implement `IEnumerable`, even though there are no calls to `GetEnumerator()`.

Comment: More interesting background info here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madst/archive/2006/10/10/what-is-a-collection_3f00_.aspx

Comment: @Jon: Interesting observation about the order. Fixed. Thanks. Added `IEnumerable` requirement too.

Comment: I'll check the C# specification more often when I find myself wondering about the answer of this kind of question. Thanks for sharing the explatation about how collection initializers works was available there.