# Dictionary initializer has different behavior and raises run-time exception when used in combination of array initializer

Tags: c#, dictionary, initialization, c#-6.0

I have the following C# code which initializes a new dictionary with `int` keys and `List<string>` values:

```
var dictionary =
    new Dictionary<int, List<string>>
    {
        [1] = new List<string> { "str1", "str2", "str3" },
        [2] = new List<string> { "str4", "str5", "str6" }
    };
```

If I decompile an executable made from this snippet back to C# the corresponding part looks like this:

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> expr_06 = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
expr_06[1] = new List<string>
{
    "str1",
    "str2",
    "str3"
};
expr_06[2] = new List<string>
{
    "str4",
    "str5",
    "str6"
};
```

Everything seems normal and is working properly here.

But when I have the following code:

```
var dictionary2 =
    new Dictionary<int, List<string>>
    {
        [1] = { "str1", "str2", "str3" },
        [2] = { "str4", "str5", "str6" }
    };
```

which again seems like normal code and compiles successfully, but during runtime I get the following exception:

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key was not present in the dictionary.'

When I look into the decompiled code of the second example I can see that it is different from the first one:

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> expr_6E = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
expr_6E[1].Add("str1");
expr_6E[1].Add("str2");
expr_6E[1].Add("str3");
expr_6E[2].Add("str4");
expr_6E[2].Add("str5");
expr_6E[2].Add("str6");
```

And of course this explains the exception.

So now my questions are:

1. **Is this expected behavior and is it documented somewhere?**
2. **Why is the syntax above allowed but the following syntax is not?**

   ```
   List<string> list = { "test" };
   ```
3. **Why is the following syntax not allowed then?**

   ```
   var dict = new Dictionary<int, string[]>
   {
       [1] = { "test1", "test2", "test3" },
       [2] = { "test4", "test5", "test6" }
   };
   ```

---

Similar but different questions:

- [What happens under the hood when using array initialization syntax to initialize a Dictionary instance on C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908804/what-happens-under-the-hood-when-using-array-initialization-syntax-to-initialize?rq=1)
- [How to make inline array initialization work like e.g. Dictionary initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174388/how-to-make-inline-array-initialization-work-like-e-g-dictionary-initialization?rq=1)

Comment: With `new List<string> `, you're assigning a new object to a key. Without `new`, that syntax is for initializing an existing collection object. But there isn't one. I'm surprised it compiles.

Comment: @EdPlunkett The compiler can't know that you're initializing a value that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Servy OK, `{ [1] = new List<string>(),
                [1] = { "foo", "bar", "baz" } }` is peculiar, but it works -- if `TValue` is `List<String>`. But as it turns out, that second case doesn't compile because `TValue` is `string[]`, which doesn't have an `Add()` method; I didn't notice the second one was an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me try to answer all of your questions:

---

> 1. **Is this expected behavior and is it documented somewhere?**

Yes, it is documented in the C# 6.0 Language Specification under sections §7.6.11.2 *Object initializers* and §7.6.11.3  *Collection initializers*.

The syntax

```
var a =
    new Test
    {
        [1] = "foo"
        [2] = "bar"
    };
```

was actually newly introduced in C# 6.0 as an extension of the previous object initialization syntax to indexers. An object initializer used together with `new` (see *object creation expression*, §7.6.11) always translates to object instantiation and member access of the corresponding object (using a temporary variable), in this case:

```
var _a = new Test();
_a[1] = "foo";
_a[2] = "bar";
var a = _a;
```

The collection initializer goes similar besides that each element of the initializer is passed as an argument to the `Add` method of the newly created collection:

```
var list = new List<int> {1, 2};
```

becomes

```
var _list = new List<int>();
_list.Add(1);
_list.Add(2);
var list = _list;
```

An object initializer can also contain other object or collection initializers. The specification states for the case of collection initializers:

> A member initializer that specifies a collection initializer after the
>   equals sign is an initialization of an embedded collection. Instead of
>   assigning a new collection to the target field, property or indexer,
>   the elements given in the initializer are added to the collection
>   referenced by the target.

So a sole collection initalizer used within an object initializer will not attempt to create a new collection instance. It will only try to add the elements to an exisiting collection, i.e. a collection that was already instantiated in the constructor of the parent object.

Writing

```
[1] = new List<string> { "str1", "str2", "str3" }
```

is actually a totally different case because this is an *object creation expression* which  only *contains* an collection initializer, but isn't one.

---

> 2. **Why is the syntax above allowed but the following 
>      syntax is not?**
>
>    ```
>    List<string> list = { "test" };
>    ```

Now, this is not a collection initializer anymore. A collection initalizer can only occur inside an object initializer or in an object creation expression. A sole `{ obj1, obj2 }` next to an assignment is actually an `array initializer` (§12.6). The code does not compile since you can't assign an array to a `List<string>`.

---

> 3. **Why is the following syntax not allowed then?**
>
>    ```
>    var dict = new Dictionary<int, string[]> 
>    {
>        [1] = { "test1", "test2", "test3" },
>        [2] = { "test4", "test5", "test6" }     
>    };
>    ```

It is not allowed because collection initalizers are only allowed to initialize **collections**, not array types (since only collections have an `Add` method).

Comment: Actually this one answers all of my questions. I will accept it if no one provides a better one.

Answer (score 4):

Using a list-initializer (that is using `= { "test1", "test2", "test3" }`) assumes the list already was initialized in some way, e.g. in the class´ constructor to something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    List<string> TheList = new List<string>();
}
```

Now you can use the list-initializer:

```
var m = new MyClass { TheList = { myElementsHere } };
```

As you already showed this is just a shortcut to calling the `Add`-method.

However in your case the list is not initialized at all making the call to the list-initializer raise the mentioned exception. Just declaring a `Dictionary` whose values are lists of any type doesn´t mean you already initialized those lists. You have to do this as with any other class before you can call any of its methods (e.g. `Add` which is just wrapped within the initializer).

Comment: there are few spelling mistake in your write-up ... just a FYI